# struct error :"no matching function for call to "

Tags: c++, struct

i just do a test that have question add two fraction, but getting an error,

> no matching function for call to 'fraction::fraction()'

my code(incomplete):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct fraction{
    int numerator, denominator;
    fraction (int _numerator, int _denominator){
        numerator=_numerator;
        denominator=_denominator;
    }
};

fraction add(fraction a, fraction b){
    fraction result;
    result.numerator=a.numerator*b.denominator;
    result.denominator=a.denominator*b.numerator;
    return result;
}
void reduce(fraction &a)
{
    int n=0;
    for(int i=a.numerator;i>=1;i--)
    {
        if(a.numerator%i==0&&a.denominator%i==0)
        {
            n==i;
        }
    }
    a.numerator/=n;
    a.denominator/=n;

}
```

Comment: Looks like implicit constructor call. Somewere outside of code  presented.

Comment: @ephemerr No, it's right there, in `add()`

Comment: Recommendation:  pass structures by references to avoid unnecessary copying.  Prefer `const` reference if the parameter is not modified by the function.

Comment: You may want to: 1) put the `add` function into your structure; 2) Overload `operator +=` inside your structure.

Answer (score 3):

In your `add` function you have

```
fraction result;
```

This will attempt to default-construct the `result` object. But the `fraction` class does not have a default constructor, which is what the error message is telling you.

To solve this you need to either add a default constructor to the `fraction` class, or use something like

```
fraction add(fraction a, fraction b){
    return fraction(a.numerator*b.denominator, a.denominator*b.numerator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` function uses

```
fraction result;
```

which will try to find the `fraction::fraction()` constructor your error is complaining it can't find.

Your struct has one constructor which takes two numbers:

```
fraction (int _numerator, int _denominator)
```

so you need to provide two numbers when you make `result`:

```
fraction result(0, 0);
```

There are other soultions, but this is the essence of what the error means.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined but a single binary constructor. In such cases nullary constructor is not implicitly defined so you'll need to add to your class something like

```
fraction() = default;
```

Or simply construct result properly:

```
fraction add(fraction a, fraction b){
    fraction result(a.numerator * b.denominator, a.denominator * b.numerator);
    return result;
}
```

Note that result calculation is incomplete in the snippet you've provided (and I simply copied the formulas from your code.)

Comment: Or just `return { a.numerator * b.denominator, a.denominator * b.numerator };`

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, or just that. :)

Answer (score 1):

`fraction::fraction()` would be the default constructor and your struct does not have any.

As soon as you declared the *non-default* constructor `fraction(int _numerator, int _denominator)` the compiler stopped supplying its own default ctor (and you didn't write one to compensate).

And you attempt to call the (not existing) default ctor when you do `fraction result;`, so now you are in trouble; you try to call a function that does not exist and the compiler is kindly telling you that.

If you don't need/want to provide your own default constructor for the struct, but are fine with what the compiler would have generated, had you not supplied your own non-default constructor, then you can tell the compiler to "please give me your default ctor for this struct" with `fraction() = default;`. Just be sure that that is what you want and that you don't actually want to implement your own custom default ctor (alternatively, rework your code so it doesn't contain any invocation of the default ctor).